core.setOutput cannot be accessed with GitHub Actions
When I try to run a simple script like this one below my output is always empty:
- uses: actions/github-script@v6
  id: hello-world
  with:
    script: |
      core.setOutput('MY_OUTPUT', 'hello world')
- name: Use versions
  run: |
    echo "Output: ${{ steps.hello-world.outputs.MY_OUTPUT }}"

Other fuctions like core.setFailed seem to work but I doesn't matter what I try my output is always empty in the next step.
Already searched but found no real solution except to just return <value> which works but just for a single variable. When I want to set several variables, it does not work anymore (or at least I'm not sure which syntax to use. Tried it already with returning an object)

Have you tried v7 i.e. actions/github-script@v7? See https://github.com/actions/github-script?tab=readme-ov-file#breaking-changes.

Omg, I don't know how I could missed that. Would of course the first thing to try the newest version. It works now, thank you so much.
Still wondering a little bit why it silently fails and some parts of v6 are working but not setOutput.

You're welcome! You might want to configure Dependabot for GitHub Actions to automate these version updates.
